Showing $ \{ x \in V : d(x,x_0)<d(x,x_1) \} $ is open.
Let $V$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Fix $x_0, x_1\in V$. I am trying to show that the set
$$ U:=\{ x \in V : d(x,x_0)<d(x,x_1) \} $$ is open.
This seems like it should be super easy and no doubt it is.
This is what I've tried.
Let $y\in U$ so $d(y,x_0)<d(y,x_1)$.
Now let $\epsilon=d(y,x_1)-d(y,x_0)>0$.
I think it should hold that $ B_{\epsilon }(y) \subseteq U.$
Let $z \in B_\epsilon(y)$.
Then $d(z,x_0) \leq d(z,y)+d(y,x_0) < \epsilon + d(y,x_0)=d(y,x_1).$
Obviously the final $y$ should be a $z$ and then it would work but I don't know where a $d(z,x_1)$ term could come from.

Your $\epsilon$ is too large. Consider an example with $V = \mathbf R$ to see this. Maybe try $\epsilon/2$ instead.

Set $f(x)= d(x,x_0)-d(x,x_i)$ which is obviously continuous. Since $U_i=f^{-1}((-\infty ,0))$, it's obviously open.

You should try taking $\varepsilon = \frac{d(y,x_1)-d(y, x_0)}{2}$. Then for $z\in B_\varepsilon (y)$ we have
$$ d(z,x_0)\leq d(z,y)+d(y,x_0)<\varepsilon +d(y, x_0)=d(y, x_1)-\varepsilon < d(y,x_1)-d(z, y)\leq d(z, x_1) $$
and we are done.

+1, well done !
